# Get subpath when there is connection between concrete node and each node in subpath

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have events ordered in a chain according to its dates. See [example](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ba9e6h). I want to get subpaths that have happend on specific date. Lets say that date is known. I have written this:

```
START d=node(73)  // date node
MATCH node=d-[:WHEN]->(l)<-[:FOLLOWS*0..]-(f)<-[:WHEN]-d RETURN f,l;
```

And it seems to work more or less OK. But I have two issues:

- It returns two items as result. There some are little issues with parsing. Can I unite this two values into whole path?
- I'm not very sure about order. Can it be possible that 1st element in sequence `l` is last element in the path?

I think that it will be easier to construct paths if I will know last element in subpath to find. Is it posible to get last element which belongs to this date (it means last element should belong this date and next to him should be absent or belong to another date) ?

UPDATE: I have found a way to merge values into collenction:

```
START d=node(74) 
MATCH node=d-[:WHEN]->(l)<-[:FOLLOWS*0..]-(f)<-[:WHEN]-d WITH [ f,l ] as qwe 
RETURN qwe;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the path you can do:

```
START d=node(73)  // date node
MATCH (d)-[:WHEN]->(l),(d)-[:WHEN]->(f), 
      path=(l)<-[:FOLLOWS*0..]-(f)
RETURN path;

or 

RETURN nodes(path)
```

Regarding the order, as you provide the direction, this is the order that nodes will be ordered in your path.